# Using retry causes odd synchronous behavior

Tags: rxjs

When Observable `C()` fails and trigger and enters a retry, all other streams seem to be blocked.

```
Observable.combineLatest(Auth(), B())
 .switchMap(([auth, b]) => C(auth.id, b.resp)())
 .retry(2)
 .subscribe({})
```

The `Auth` function returns a Observable that is structured as

```
Stream.take(1)
  .map(s => s.userSession)
  .filter(s => s.type === 'AuthedUserSession')
  .map(assertAsAuthedSession)
```

`Auth` is used in a few other places with a `combineLatest` joiner. `B()` is a ajax observable. I've tried using `retryWhen` when a delay but it seems  to be behaving the same. Is it possible that I blocked everywhere that uses `Auth()` by using it with the retry block?

Comment: you need to provide more information about the behavior you are experiencing.  What do you mean by "all other streams seem to be blocked".  Other usages of `Auth()`?  What is `Stream`?  What do you mean by "blocked"?

Answer (score 0):

Try ‘forkJoin’ instead ‘combineLatest’, Looks more convenient in your case. Not sure if it fixes issue can you setup playground for your case?